# Apply lapply function on forecast package (accuracy and auto.arima)

Tags: r, lapply, forecast

I am foresting data set uschange from fpp2 package and function from the forecast package auto.arima. Because I forecasting several time series in the same time I used own function which make several projections simultaneously.

```
# 
library(fpp2) # data
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)

MY_DATA<-uschange[,1:4]

Trening_set<-subset(MY_DATA,start=1,end=150) # Training set
Test_set<-subset(MY_DATA,start=151,end=187) # Test set 20% of observations

# 1.Own functions for forecasting
FORECASTING_FUNCTION_ARIMA <- function(Z, hrz = 16) {
  timeseries <- msts(Z, start = 1970, seasonal.periods = 4)
  forecast <- auto.arima(timeseries)
  #ic = c("bic")
}
FORECASTING_LIST_ARIMA <- lapply(X = Trening_set, FORECASTING_FUNCTION_ARIMA)
ARIMA_MODELS_FORECAST<-lapply(FORECASTING_LIST_ARIMA, forecast,h=37)
```

In order to see accuracy of this models I used lapply function.So code and results you can see below:

```
# Accurancy test
ACCURANCY_ARIMA <- lapply(FORECASTING_LIST_ARIMA,  accuracy)
```

So next step should be how to use same function in order to produce same accuracy errors like in previous example but now with test set. I try with code below but something is wrong and I can't get good results.

```
 ACCURANCY_ARIMA1<-lapply(FORECASTING_LIST_ARIMA, accuracy(forecast(ARIMA_MODELS_ALL,h=37),x=Test_set))
```

If this function work properly output should look like this table below (numbers are only for illustration).

[image]

So can anybody help me how to fix this code line and get output similar like last pic above.

Comment: How do you run `accuracy` for 1 model? If I do this `accuracy(forecast(FORECASTING_LIST_ARIMA[[1]],h=37), x = Test_set)` it gives an error `Error in testaccuracy(object, x, test, d, D) : 
  Not enough forecasts. Check that forecasts and test data match.`

Comment: I think this is answer for your question.This is how look like this example only on one time series without own function.This line of code work properly                       MY_DATA_1<-uschange[,1:1]

Trening_set_1<-subset(MY_DATA_1,start=1,end=150)
Test_set_1<-subset(MY_DATA_1,start=151,end=187)

FORECASTING_LIST_ARIMA_1<-auto.arima(Trening_set_1)
accuracy(forecast(FORECASTING_LIST_ARIMA_1,h=37),x=Test_set_1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(forecast)

ACCURACY_ARIMA <- Map(function(x, y) accuracy(forecast(x, h = 37), 
        x = Test_set[, y]), FORECASTING_LIST_ARIMA, seq_len(ncol(Test_set)))

ACCURACY_ARIMA
#$Consumption
#                   ME RMSE  MAE MPE MAPE MASE  ACF1 Theil's U
#Training set  0.00082 0.61 0.45  62  192 0.66 0.018        NA
#Test set     -0.44644 0.66 0.49 165  346 0.72 0.629      0.67

#$Income
#                   ME RMSE  MAE MPE MAPE MASE   ACF1 Theil's U
#Training set  4.2e-15 0.86 0.60  40  163 0.63 -0.056        NA
#Test set     -3.4e-01 1.18 0.69  20  212 0.72 -0.326      0.65

#$Production
#                  ME RMSE  MAE MPE MAPE MASE   ACF1 Theil's U
#Training set  0.0094  1.3 0.88  36  114 0.59 -0.021        NA
#Test set     -0.6538  1.8 1.05  18  124 0.71  0.771         1

#$Savings
#              ME RMSE  MAE MPE MAPE MASE   ACF1 Theil's U
#Training set 1.2   12  8.1 111  176 0.65 -0.012        NA
#Test set     2.5   19 11.9 101  101 0.96 -0.356      0.97
```

Comment: I tried this function.This function produce results with Training and Test set, but one thing is not correct. Namely this function ACCURACY_ARIMA work only with one time series (Consumption) which is embedded into Test_set_1. Originally in Test_set described in my first post contain four time series (Consumption,Income,Production and Savings).So please check if you can.Thank you in advance

Comment: @silent_hunter I have updated the answer, You can check now.